# How to select a specific node with LINQ-to-XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I can select the first customer node and change its company name with the code below.

But how do I select customer node where ID=2?

```
    XDocument xmldoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XComment("These are all the customers transfered from the database."),
        new XElement("Customers",
            new XElement("Customer",
                new XAttribute("ID", 1),
                new XElement("FullName", "Jim Tester"),
                new XElement("Title", "Developer"),
                new XElement("Company", "Apple Inc.")
                ),
            new XElement("Customer",
                new XAttribute("ID", 2),
                new XElement("FullName", "John Testly"),
                new XElement("Title", "Tester"),
                new XElement("Company", "Google")
                )
            )
        );

    XElement elementToChange = xmldoc.Element("Customers").Element("Customer").Element("Company");
    elementToChange.ReplaceWith(new XElement("Company", "new company value..."));
```

### ANSWER:

Thanks guys, for the record, here is the exact syntax to search out the company element in the customer-with-id-2 element, and then change only the value of the company element:

```
XElement elementToChange = xmldoc.Element("Customers")
    .Elements("Customer")
    .Single(x => (int)x.Attribute("ID") == 2)
    .Element("Company");
elementToChange.ReplaceWith(
    new XElement("Company", "new company value...")
    );
```

### ANSWER WITH METHOD SYNTAX:

Just figured it out in method syntax as well:

```
XElement elementToChange = (from c in xmldoc.Element("Customers")
                                .Elements("Customer")
                            where (int)c.Attribute("ID") == 3
                            select c).Single().Element("Company");
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assuming the ID is unique:

```
var result = xmldoc.Element("Customers")
                   .Elements("Customer")
                   .Single(x => (int?)x.Attribute("ID") == 2);
```

You could also use `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `SingleOrDefault` or `Where`, instead of `Single` for different circumstances.

Comment: why does this give me the error: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no extension method 'Single' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' found

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq` on top of your source?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use something like:

```
dim customer = (from c in xmldoc...<Customer> 
                where c.<ID>.Value=22 
                select c).SingleOrDefault
```

Edit:

missed the c# tag, sorry......the example is in VB.NET

Comment: Any chance of a conversion of this to C#?

Comment: @Hexie it's always a big benefit being multilingual. 
For whatever reason, VB people can work in C#; but not to often the other way.