# Identifying a certain node in XML

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, dataset

```
<enviNFe versao="1.10">
  <idLote>000000000000094</idLote> 
  <NFe>
    <infNFe Id="NFe35090254517628000198550010000000011870030005" versao="1.10">
    <!-- ... content ... -->
    </infNFe>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <!-- ... content ... -->
    </Signature>
  </NFe>
</enviNFe>
```

I have this XML file, how do i get the ID attribute? this question is not about "how to get attributes in xml's", i've found several solutions, but somehow i can't address to this specific attribute in this specific node.

i can get info inside tables that are within "infNF" and i'm loading it into a dataset and using this code:

```
ds.Tables(Table).Rows(row)(node)
```

is there a similar way to do what i want to get THIS attribute ?

(you can answer either in C# or VB.NET)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ds.Tables("infNFe").Rows(0).Item(2)
```

That's what i've used, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried XQuery?

```
 var node = element.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe[@id='...']")
```

And by the looks of the XML it appears you're dealing with Brazilian NFe, right?

---

**Edited to Add**

You can find more about XQuery [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/).

Once you past the brackets... you'll see it's quite simple.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it, and how should i read the xml to perform this ? i've never used xquery

Comment: XmlDocument slideDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
slideDoc.Load("filePath");
XmlNode titleNode = slideDoc.SelectSingleNode("//p:sp//p:ph[@type='title' or @type='ctrTitle']", nsManager);

Comment: @Paulo Santos tem algum contato pra podermos conversar? é bom ter contatos de desenvolvedores =)

Answer (score 0):

If you have .Net 3.5 then use linq see [How to select a specific node with LINQ-to-XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594231/how-to-select-a-specific-node-with-linq-to-xml)