# How to search for a substring

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I retrieve xml with several nodes this type

```
<pickUpPoint puCost="0" code4county="UK*LINCS" puKey="C021P008">
    Louth
</pickUpPoint>
```

and I've got a string formed from the puKey and the actual value of the node (ie C021P008Louth). What I'm trying to achieve is to search in the whole document for the actual node, but I'm not able for the moment to do something like this

```
xDataForLINQ.Descendants("pickUpPoint")
            .Where(pp =>(tourPickUp.Contains(pp.Attribute("puKey").Value)) = true)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

and then check if the value matches the second part of my string (using contains as well).

Comment: Have a look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/594231/1437962 , also consider this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675173(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I tried to put a comment of what I've done so far and answered my own question instead.

Comment: This is what I did eventually

pickUpPointNode = xDataForLINQ.Descendants("pickUpPoint").FirstOrDefault(pp => (tourPickUp.Contains(pp.Attribute("puKey").Value)) && (tourPickUp.Contains(pp.Value)));

Don't know if it's the best thing but it seems to work

Comment: No problem, did you tried my references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using

```
xDataForLINQ.Descendants("pickUpPoint")
            .FirstOrDefault(p => (string) p.Attribute("puKey") + p.Value == tourPickUp)
```

is clearer and more precise.